# Why does a parent's offsetHeight ignore its child's margin unless the parent has a border?

Tags: css, margin, offsetheight

1) In a simple parent-child relationship, the inner child generally affects the `outerHeight` of the parent:

```
<div id="outer1">
  <div>hello</div>
</div>
```

`outer1.offsetHeight == 18`

2) If the inner child is given a `margin`, the parent's `outerHeight` doesn't change:

```
<div id="outer2">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">hello</div>
</div>
```

`outer2.offsetHeight == 18`

3) If the parent is then given a `border`, then it *does* take the child's `margin` into account:

```
<div id="outer3" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">hello</div>
</div>
```

`outer3.offsetHeight == 30`

**I thought `outerHeight` measures its height up to and including its border. Why does it include the child's margin, but only if the parent has a border?**

Answer (score 3):

So long as the parent has no border, there is the possibility that the child's bottom margin might be [collapsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) with another element below it. Once the border is defined, that's not possible.

Comment: still doesn't make any sense to me. Child's margin may be collapsed with some element below it, so what? why does the parent's height doesn't get affected by the margin of its child. And why is it affected when the parent has some border? could you please make some elaboration on this. thanks in advance.